# Custom formset validation not working in django

Tags: python, django, validation

In my formset I would like to check each reading against a target if the reading is larger than the target do not save to db. For some reason I can't get this to work correctly because it still allows me to save. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

all in views.py

```
     #custom formset validation 
def get_dim_target(target): 
   dim = Dimension.objects.values_list('target', flat=True).filter(id=target) 
   return dim 

#custom formset validation 
class BaseInspecitonFormSet(BaseFormSet): 
  def insp_clean(self): 
     if any(self.errors): 
       return 
     reading = [] 
     for form in self.forms: 
       dim_id = form.cleanded_data['dimension_id'] 
       reading = form.cleaned_data['reading'] 

       target = get_dim_target(dim_id) 
       if reading > target: 
         raise forms.ValidationError("Reading larger than target") 
       reading.append(reading) 

      #formset 
def update_inspection_vals(request, dim_id=None): 
  dims_data = Dimension.objects.filter(id=dim_id) 
  can_delete = False 
  dims = Dimension.objects.get(pk=dim_id) 
  sheet_data = Sheet.objects.get(pk=dims.sheet_id) 
  serial_sample_number = Inspection_vals.objects.filter(dimension_id=24).values_list('serial_number', flat=True)[0] 
  target = Dimension.objects.filter(id=24).values_list('target', flat=True)[0] 
  title_head = 'Inspect-%s' % dims.description 

  if dims.ref_dim_id == 1: 
    inspection_inline_formset = inlineformset_factory(Dimension, Inspection_vals, can_delete=False, extra=0, fields=('reading',), widgets={ 
      'reading': forms.TextInput(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}) 
    }) 

  if request.method == "POST": 
    formset = inspection_inline_formset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=dims) 
    if formset.is_valid():   

      new_instance = formset.save(commit=False) 
      for n_i in new_instance: 

        n_i.created_at = datetime.datetime.now() 
        n_i.updated_at = datetime.datetime.now() 
        n_i.save() 
    else: 
      form_errors = formset.errors 
      formset.non_form_errors() 

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')) 
  else: 
    formset = inspection_inline_formset(instance=dims, queryset=Inspection_vals.objects.filter(dimension_id=dim_id).order_by('serial_number')) 

  return render(request, 'app/inspection_vals.html', 
   { 
     'formset': formset, 
     'dim_data': dims_data, 
     'title':title_head, 
     'dim_description': dims.description, 
     'dim_target': dims.target, 
     'work_order': sheet_data.work_order, 
     'customer_name': sheet_data.customer_name, 
     'serial_sample_number': serial_sample_number, 
   })
```

inspection_val.html

```
  <h1>Inspeciton Values</h1> 
  <div class="well"> 
    <form method="post"> 
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <table> 
      {{ formset.management_form }} 
      {% for x in formset.forms %} 
        <tr> 
          <td>         
              Sample Number {{ forloop.counter0|add:serial_sample_number }} 
          </td> 
          <td> 
              {{ x }} 
              {{ x.errors }} 
          </td> 
        </tr> 
      {% endfor %} 
    </table> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Values" class="btn-primary" /> 
    </form> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django docs on [custom formset validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) show that you should create a `clean` method.

You have named your method `insp_clean`, so Django will never call it. Rename the method to `clean`.